# Stop the call of js method in Firebug console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firebug, jquery-events

I have a question... So I have an popup and this popup is shown after click on the button. In this popup a I have and ads. After user complete the ads I call the method .js :

```
function completeAds()
    {
        bonusPurchase();
        update();
        document.getElementById('test-pub').setAttribute('class','not-display');
    }
```

`bonusPurchase()` means that for this user I added some bonus. Now the problem is that if I open the popup and I write in the console of Firebug in Mozilla :

```
bonusPurchase();
update();
```

The user get the bonus without complete ads. It a way to stop it?

Comment: Make them [private](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)!

Comment: Is not another posibilite ?

Comment: There is no way to protect any kind of  process if this process is done client side. You should set your logic server side

Comment: Thx, and any ideas ? I'm newbie in js :(

Comment: @HareaCosticla This is too broad question, i don't know what you call a bonus and process used to check its availability regarding `completeAds()`. Now if you expect your user to click on random ads to get a bonus (and you get the money...)=, just do it client side because anyway this is against all advertiser compagny TOS, so really, who cares...